# Gremlin.sh Error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fusesource/jansi/AnsiRenderWriter

Tags: java, maven, gremlin

When I execute a recently installed Gremlin by /bin/gremlin.sh I got:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fusesource/jansi/AnsiRenderWriter

```
at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.console.Console.<init>(Console.java:71)
at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.console.Console.main(Console.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiRenderWriter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: What version of Gremlin?  Is it a packaged version you downloaded? What version of Java are you using?  OS?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

I Downloaded Gremlin version 2.4 from :
[link](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Downloads)

Mac OS

@stephenmallete

Answer (score 0):

The [jansi](http://jansi.fusesource.org/download.html) library is not in your classpath.